# merge hash same key in array of hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have a array of hash which contains resources key in every block like below

```
[ 
  {
    "resources": {
       "abc": "...some data..."
     }
  },
  {
    "resources": {
       "xyz": "...some data..."
     }
  },
  #...
 ]
```

so like to convert it like

```
{
  "resources": {
    "abc": "...some data...",
    "xyz": "...some data...",
    # etc...
  }
}
```

I have tried so many things but did not get the actual result.. : (

Comment: When you give an example, please make it complete and self-contained (no `...`) so that those who offer answers can apply them to your example. Examples should be as concise as possible and you should show your desired result. Please also assign variables to input objects (e.g., `arr = [...]`, but w/o the dots :-) ) so that readers can cut-and-paste and refer to those variables in answers and comments.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful advise :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Rails Active Support's Hash extension to do deep merge

```
require "active_support/core_ext/hash"
array.reduce(&:deep_merge)
#=> {:resources=>{:abc=>"some data", :xyz=>"some data"}}
```

If you don't want to use that `active_support` gem, you can copy the `deep_merge` method from the it's source - [active_support/core_ext/hash/deep_merge.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/deep_merge.rb)

Comment: Good answer. No Rails tag but OP doesn't seem to mind.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks. That's why I shared the link to raw source as well - as I would hate to write a recursive method to do this all over again.

Answer (score 3):

```
array.inject{|h, _h| h.merge(_h){|_, h1, h2| h1.merge(h2)}}
```